# Python: outside function applying changes to a class object's unique namespace

Tags: class, namespaces, python-2.6

My question is how to program in Python (2.6) a function that uses a namespace of an object, while the function is defined outside the object/class. In addition, that function should only change the variables in the object's namespace; it should not take over the namespace (because with multiple objects they will all use the same namespace).

My reason for pursuing this, is because I wish to write a very small class, where during construction all necessary functions for future use are already given and subsequent function calls (`self.__call__`) on the object itself can be directly applied.

I realize that this idea is not very pythonic (as they say), and I have thought of various other solutions (such as putting the functions in another class and connecting them), but I can't help but feel that each of these solutions is a lot more work than I would think makes sense.

One simple way that accomplishes what I want is the following:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, some_dict, func_a):
        self.memory = some_dict
        self.__call__ = func_a

def test_func(obj, some_input):
    if some_input in obj.memory :
        return obj.memory[some_input]
    else :
        obj.memory[some_input] = 0. # some default value
        return 0.

first_object = A({}, test_func)
print first_object(first_object, '3')
```

This will work fine, but what aches me is that when I make function calls to the object, I will also have to give the object itself (see the last line). I hope to be able make calls as such:

```
print first_object('3')
```

So far, my ideas were unsuccesful to avoid this (e.g. copying the function method and link its namespace by `self.__call__.memory = self.memory`). I wish to find something to change the `def __init__` part to 'adopt' a function and link their namespaces.

I have rigorously searched for an answer on the internet, but a definite solution has not yet been found. The following http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t738476-inserting-class-namespace-into-method-scope.html seeks the same, but is also not succesfull.

Anyone have a solution to tackle this?

Comment: Your question seems a lot broader than your example.  If you simply want to be able to write `first_object("3")`, that's easy.  OTOH, if you want namespace hackery like in your linked question, that's going to be a lot harder.  Would the first suffice?

Comment: That would suffice, but I can't help but feel with the way I structured my code that it would necessitate namespace hackery?